# C++ Error: Type Name is Not Allowed

Tags: c++

I'm trying to play around with my new class lesson in Pointer Arguments, and i want to make the functions senior and everyoneElse take pointer x, yet when I try to call the function with the pointer pAge, it says Error: Type name is not allowed. What's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>


int senior(int* x);
int everyoneElse(int* x);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age(0);
    int* pAge(&age);
    cout<<"How old are you?"<<endl;
    cin>>age;
    if(age>59)
        senior(int* pAge);
    else
        everyoneElse(int* pAge);
    return 0;
}

int senior(int* x)
{

return *x;
}

int everyoneElse(int* x)
{

return *x;
}
```

Comment: It's the same as calling any other function. You don't include a type.

Answer (score 15):

```
if(age>59)
    senior(int* pAge);
else
    everyoneElse(int* pAge);
```

You can't include the typename when calling a function.  Change to:

```
if(age>59)
    senior(pAge);
else
    everyoneElse(pAge);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
senior(int* pAge);
else
    everyoneElse(int* pAge);
```

replace with

```
senior(pAge);
else
    everyoneElse(pAge);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call the function, you do not have to specify type of parametr, that you pass to a function:

```
if(age>59)
    senior(pAge);
else
    everyoneElse(pAge);
```

Parametrs should be specified by type only in function prototype and body function (smth like this:)

```
int senior(int* x)
{

return *x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are calling the function *int senior(int* x)* and *int everyoneElse(int* x)* is wrong call the function as : **everyoneElse(pAge)** and **int senior(x)**

see link 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be6ftfba(v=vs.80).aspx**